# How to disable "Using config file" in pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I'm running pylint for several directories using a simple bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

for PACKAGE in some_dir another_dir third_dir
do
    pylint --disable=R,C $PACKAGE
done
```

I want output to be clean if everything is fine. However, there are annoying lines:

```
Using config file /home/user/projects/some-project/.pylintrc
```

Is there an option in `pylintrc` or in `pylint` command line to disable "Using config file"?

**Update:** there is an open issue https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1853

Comment: `pylint --disable=R,C $PACKAGE | grep -v "Using config file /home/user/projects/some-project/.pylintrc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Jan Jurec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2927988/) answer is  outdated, in a [posterior commit](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/search?q=verbose&type=Commits), they renamed the quiet command flag to `--verbose`. Now on, `pylint` is "quiet" by default.

However, it still not quiet enough, as by default it prints the scores like this:

```
D:\tests>pylint --disable=I,E,R,W,C,F --enable=E0102 --reports=no test.py

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: -2.50/10, +12.50)


D:\tests>
```

But you disable those with `-sn`, then the older example would became this when no problems are found:

```
D:\tests>pylint --disable=I,E,R,W,C,F --enable=E0102 --reports=no -sn test.py
D:\tests>
```

And if some problem is found, the output would be like this:

```
D:\tests>pylint --disable=I,E,R,W,C,F --enable=E0102 --reports=no -sn test.py
************* Module test
test.py:6:0: E0102: class already defined line 3 (function-redefined)
D:\tests>
```

Instead of this default:

```
D:\tests>pylint --disable=I,E,R,W,C,F --enable=E0102 --reports=no test.py
************* Module test
test.py:6:0: E0102: class already defined line 3 (function-redefined)

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -2.50/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, -12.50)


D:\tests>
```

#### References

1. [pylint: error: no such option: --quiet](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2195)
2. [Still not quiet enough](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2202)

Answer (score 2):

If it is still relevant to anyone, this [PR to pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/commit/49eae8a9d6e713323cf1a6d6a469ff340255fd6b) solves the issue. From `pylint 2.0` you can just pass `--quiet` flag to `pylint`.

Edit: If you use older pylint, you may redirect and exclude with `grep`:
`pylint 2>&1 | grep -v "Using config file"`